# R: Renaming a single entry in a single column

Tags: dplyr, rename

I have a dataframe "sample" with a column "ID". Each entry there is a string variable, e.g. AB1900. I'd like to rename this entry to 001. How do I do this? There's a lot of info on how to change entire columns, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Thus far I've tried

```
sample_code <- rename (sample
                   "001" = "AB1900"
                   )
```

resulting in

> Error in rename(sample$vp_initials, `001` = "AB1900") :
> unused argument (`001` = "AB1900")

Cheers
Felix

PS: I use tidyverse, plyr and dplyr

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the probelem was. Apparently some errors occured while reading out the file with read_csv

Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) :
invalid first argument
Error in assign(cacheKey, frame, .rs.CachedDataEnv) :
attempt to use zero-length variable name

This, in turn, made the commands malfunction.

Now I've imported an Excel-file via the buttons of R Studio and used the following code - and it worked:
sample$ID[sample$ID == "AB1900"] <- "001"

Cheers
Felix

Answer (score 0):

As i understand here is the example with the answer, please check and let me know

```r
library(dplyr)
sample <- data.frame(ID='AB1900') %>% rename(sample_001=ID)

  sample_001
1     AB1900
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work

I tried

sample_1 <- sample(ID="AB1900") %>% rename(sample_001=ID)

and

sample_1 <- data.frame(ID="AB1900") %>% rename(sample_001=ID)

in both cases the error message is

Error in rename(., sample_001 = ID) : unused argument (sample_001 = ID)

Any clue what it might stem from? Cheers Felix

Comment: did you call the `library(dplyr)` and then run `sample_1 <- data.frame(ID="AB1900") %>% rename(sample_001=ID)`